# Warning messages during python selenium script : Late ncyInfo vector size

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Rarely, I see below message during execution of the script. Can someone tell me what is the reason for this?  Is it due to script or because of the application I am working on?

[7192:4260:1209/122546:ERROR:latency_info.cc(157)] RenderWidgetHostImpl::OnSwapCompositorFrame, Late
ncyInfo vector size 323 is too big.

Comment: I am getting this error frequently. I am not sure what is causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Which driver are you using for your script? I've run in to this problem with Chromedriver and assumed it was due to a buffer/latency issue when posting data to a text field.

By breaking this data up in to smaller chunks, I resolved the issue. I did this manually as it was just one section, but you might want to create a function that takes larger data and splits it in to smaller chunks if you do this a lot.

I've also heard it is specific to Chrome, but have not had a chance to test this in other browsers.